# Akka batch processing/one-item processing

Tags: java, scala, akka

I am currently implementing a system that calls an API method for a message received in Akka. This is pretty straightforward and doesn't involve anything with a deep knowledge of Akka.

The actual API though allows us to make batch requests as well (something like JSON-RPC batch call described here: http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification). The return values of the methods would not change, but the queueing would.

My idea would be to check if we have more than one message in the queue and process them all at once in one API call rather than making hundreds of separate ones (of course with the idea of replying to all of them separately).

Is that possible with Akka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such built in construct. What you can do is to have a batching actor in front of your processing actor. When the batching actor gets a new reply, it starts building up a batch.

The processor actor can ask the batching actor when it is ready to process the next batch. At this point the batching actor sends out all the messages it collected so far in one message.

Of course the actual pattern would be somewhat different depending on how and when is the API called.

But before you start building such a pattern, you should actually measure the performance. I personally prefer actors to do fine grained work instead of large chunks. If you do too much work in one receive action, you might reduce fairness.

If you can live with reduced fairness for potentially (although not necessarily) higher throughput, you should look into the "throughput" setting of the default dispatcher:

```
# Throughput defines the maximum number of messages to be
# processed per actor before the thread jumps to the next actor.
# Set to 1 for as fair as possible.
```